# Bind SelectedValue of ASP.net DropDownList to nested property

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

*(first of all, it seems this is a subject that is discussed many times before, but I can't find a proper answer for my case)*

I have a asp.net FormView with a DropDownList for the selection of a month. The FormView is data bound to an ObjectDataSource.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MonthsList" DataSourceID="MonthsListDataSource" DataTextField="Value" DataValueField="Key" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("OrderDate.Month") %>' Width="100" runat="server" />
```

I like to bind the selected value to the nested property 'Month' of 'OrderDate' as shown above. The property OrderDate is of type DateTime. The error I'm getting while binding to a nested property is:

> A call to Bind was not well formatted.  Please refer to documentation for the correct parameters to Bind.

What is the best solution to be able to bind to a nested propety?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you retrieving data from DataSourceID="MonthsListDataSource" and tryingo to bind it to another DataBase field (SelectedValue='<%# Eval("OrderDate.Month") %>') ?

In my application a do this like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MonthsList" DataSourceID="MonthsListDataSource" DataTextField="Value" DataValueField="Key" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("MonthsListDataSource.Month") %>' Width="100" runat="server" />
```

And when Updating a retrieve de DropDownList with find control, get its selected value, associate it to other table (OrderDate.Month) and save it.

Sorry my answer, but i dont know if a undertand it.

Comment: I like your solution, very clean one. Thanks.

Comment: @Ewerton - What will you have in the code behind to handle the binding of the selected value?

Answer (score 1):

What about using **Eval** keyword

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MonthsList" DataSourceID="MonthsListDataSource" DataTextField="Value" DataValueField="Key" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("OrderDate.Month") %>' Width="100" runat="server" />
```

Comment: hm ... this is not safe, as `SelectedValue` might throw an exception. you should rather go for the `ItemDataBound`-event!

Comment: That will do, but I'd like to use Bind(), because the selected value must be returned to the datasource when the form is submitted.

Comment: why do you want to use `Bind()`. do you need a two-way-binding?... on an immutable-type??

Comment: Nice one Andreas, looked over it. Indeed I need two-way binding, but this way it's not gonna happen for this specific type. Have to find another way. Thanks.